# veriSign SSL Cert for subdomain

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have purchase SSL for secure Site from [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/). I have configured it and its working properly on https://www.example.com . I have subdomain app.example.com . i need to work SSL on this domain also. I have 2 Questions.

1- Will same SSL will work for the `subdomain` too? **[My SSL is not wildcard SSL]**

2- If it will not work. then how can i change the same SSL that it should only work on [app.example.com](http://app.example.com). i mean is there any way to change purchased SSL for subdomain. and How can i do this.

https://www.example.com and http://app.example.com point to the same IP address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Not it will not, it will work only for the domain name for which it was signed.

2) Unfortunately this is not possible. You should get another certificate for app.example.com and make app.example.com point to another IP address or get a wildcard certificate in case you want to keep both domains on the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

First things if your SSL is not wildcard then it won't be able to protect your sub domain. SSL certificate which you bought that it will protect only web site for which it was issued. its not possible to change the SSL certificate to secure your sub domains. If you want to secure your sub domain name in this situation then you should have another SSL certificate like [WildCard SSL](https://www.rapidsslonline.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates.aspx) which will protect your sub domains and also your host names, but make sure your new SSL certificate must point to another IP address in order to use it.